# Ramda: Translate for-in loop to declarative method

Tags: ramda.js

I'm new on Ramda. May I know how to translate the code below using Ramda
I found some functions like keys, keysIn, but i have no idea how to apply them.
Thanks.

```
const params = {
    data: {
        a: 'aaa',
        b: 'bbb',
        c: 'ccc',
    }
}

let formData = new FormData();
for (let key in params.data) {
     formData.append(key, params.data.key);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `append(key, params.data[key])`?

Comment: Ramda isn't particularly designed to work with OO systems like this.  You might find something useful with [`invoker`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#invoker) but I wouldn't count on Ramda offering much help here.  Note that what you're trying to do is continual mutation of your object, something Ramda strives to avoid.

Comment: Thank you. Would you mind give some idea on my case: I received "params" from the API call, and need to translate the parameters using FormData object. How can i modify my code so apply ramda correctly?

Comment: While Ross's answer is fine, my point is that Ramda is not really designed for this sort of work.  It's not a general-purpose utility library.  It's focused on functional programming techniques, and favors immutability, referential transparency and the composition of small functions.  Trying to combine it with an OOP style is a mismatch that might be hard to work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow from what @scott said, you wouldn't really want to cause side effects from within ramda (especially from within a map fn), but if for some reason you need to you could do something like the following:

```
const params = {
    data: {
        a: 'aaa',
        b: 'bbb',
        c: 'ccc',
    }
}

let formData = new FormData();

let appender = flip(invoker(2, 'append'))(R.__, R.__, formData)

mapObjIndexed(appender)(params.data)

formData.get('a') === 'aaa' // -> true
```

Using @scott's suggestion of invoker, we can build an `appender` function which takes a key and a value, and calls `formData.append` with those. To achieve point-free style it ends up quite messy though. It can be a bit more explicit like so:

```
let appender = form => (v, k) => form.append(k, v);
mapObjIndexed(appender(formData))(params.data)
```

This has the added benefit of allowing us to provide the formData later, so whilst `appender` is still impure, it's less coupled